# Error during the compile example of tinyML

Tags: tflite, tinyml

I am studying the speech part of tinyML, but the mbed compile command is not working.
I need your help..

Shell Commands:

```
$ make -f tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/Makefile TARGET=mbed TAGS="cmsis-nn disco_f746ng" generate_micro_speech_mbed_project
```

```
$ cd tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/gen/mbed_cortex-m4/prj/micro_speech/mbed/
```

```
$ mbed config root .
C:\Python\Scripts\mbed-script.py:6: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
[mbed] . now set as default root in program "mbed"
```

```
$ mbed deploy
C:\Python\Scripts\mbed-script.py:6: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
[mbed] WARNING: Program "mbed" in "C:\SPB_Data\tensorflow-lite\tensorflow\lite\micro\tools\make\gen\mbed_cortex-m4\prj\micro_speech\mbed" does not use source control management.
       To fix this you should use "mbed new ." in the root of your program.
---
[mbed] Working path "C:\SPB_Data\tensorflow-lite\tensorflow\lite\micro\tools\make\gen\mbed_cortex-m4\prj\micro_speech\mbed" (library)
[mbed] Program path "C:\SPB_Data\tensorflow-lite\tensorflow\lite\micro\tools\make\gen\mbed_cortex-m4\prj\micro_speech\mbed"
[mbed] Updating library "AUDIO_DISCO_F746NG" to rev #7046ce26b7ed (tag: tip)
[mbed] Updating library "BSP_DISCO_F746NG" to rev #df2ea349c37a
[mbed] Updating library "LCD_DISCO_F746NG" to rev #d44525b1de98 (tag: tip)
[mbed] Updating library "mbed-os" to rev #8ef742a49c16
[mbed] Updating library "SDRAM_DISCO_F746NG" to rev #370f402a2219 (tag: tip)
```

```
$ python -c 'import fileinput, glob;
> for filename in glob.glob("mbed-os/tools/profiles/*.json"):
>     for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
>         print(line.replace("\"-std=gnu++98\"","\"-std=c++11\", \"-fpermissive\""))'
```

```
$ mbed compile -m DISCO_F746NG -t GCC_ARM
```

Error code:

```
Compile [ 89.4%]: arm_depthwise_separable_conv_HWC_q7_nonsquare.c
[Fatal Error] arm_depthwise_separable_conv_HWC_q7_nonsquare.c@409,1: opening dependency file BUILD\DISCO_F746NG\GCC_ARM\tensorflow\lite\micro\tools\make\downloads\cmsis\CMSIS\NN\Source\ConvolutionFunctions\arm_depthwise_separable_conv_HWC_q7_nonsquare.d: No such file or directory
[ERROR] '_queue.SimpleQueue' object has no attribute 'queue'
C:\Python\Scripts\mbed-script.py:6: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
[mbed] ERROR: "c:\python\python.exe" returned error.
       Code: 1
       Path: "C:\SPB_Data\tensorflow-lite\tensorflow\lite\micro\tools\make\gen\mbed_cortex-m4\prj\micro_speech\mbed"
       Command: "c:\python\python.exe -u C:\SPB_Data\tensorflow-lite\tensorflow\lite\micro\tools\make\gen\mbed_cortex-m4\prj\micro_speech\mbed\mbed-os\tools\make.py -t GCC_ARM -m DISCO_F746NG --source . --build .\BUILD\DISCO_F746NG\GCC_ARM"
       Tip: You could retry the last command with "-v" flag for verbose output
```

How can I fix this problem?

I have tried the commands:

```
$ make -f tensorflow/lite/micro/tools/make/Makefile TARGET=mbed TAGS="CMSIS-NN disco_f746ng" generate_micro_speech_mbed_project
```

but it did not worked...